# How to position div relatively to a span?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a large text in a div. In this text, I want to be able to hover on some particular words, and that will show a div below the word containing some custom div. (The same way you can hover a link in wikipedia and a summary of the linked article will show up).

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS (no javascript)?

When I add a div inside the span with relative positioning, it shits the bed. See below.

I think Wikipedia is doing it with JS.

```css
.menu-hover:hover > div {
  display: block
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  top:20px;
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Blah blah...</span>
  <span class="menu-hover">Menu
     <div class="menu">menu items</div>
  </span>
  <span>Bluh bluh...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: "When I add a div inside the span" – Start by writing valid HTML. Divs are not allowed to be descendants of spans.

Comment: @Quentin: Well I gathered that it didn't work, didn't I? The question then becomes - how do you do it?

Comment: @d-b It will still be possible with non valid HTML.

Comment: @HerrSerker: I'm not particularly looking to do a div inside a span. But it seems like custom tooltipping over a span element is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Pete: thanks. A span with display: block does not seem to work either. It behaves the same way as div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe u want this? If you want to make dropdown menu do it other way

```css
.hidden-word{
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
  font-size:11px;
}

.word{
  display:inline-block;
}
.word:hover > .hidden-word{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Blah blah...</span>
  <span class="word">some word
     <div class="hidden-word">Hidden word</div>
  </span>
  <span>Bluh bluh...</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu-hover {
  position: relative;
}

.menu-hover .menu-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vh;
}

.menu-hover .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(1.2em);
  display: none;
  background: red;
}

.menu-hover:hover .menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Blah blah...</span>
  <span class="menu-hover">Menu
    <span class="menu-wrapper">
      <span class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1
          <li>Item 2
          <li>Item 3 which is a longer item
          <li>Item 4
        </ul>
      </span>
  </span>
  </span>
  <span>Bluh bluh...</span>
</div>
```